# Fork and join nodes in UML Designer activity diagram

Tags: rotation, fork-join, activity-diagram, uml-designer

UML Designer supports [drawing UML activity diagrams](http://www.umldesigner.org/ref-doc/define-the-application.html#-manage-activities). Join and fork nodes are horizontal bars by default: [image: fork node]  [image: join node]

How can I make them vertical (flip them 90° or 270°)?

See the figure 12.95 at [UML Superstructure v2.1.1](https://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?formal/2007-02-05):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that UML Designer has [an open feature request](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/137) about this issue. So, currently...

> How can I make them vertical (flip them 90° or 270°)?

... you can't.

Comment: I confirm that is not possible.